# SQL Server Database access notifications

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have my own database in a shared server. I have set up VBA to allow users to manipulate data on this database.

Is there a way to set up notifications every time someone accesses a particular database in server? Or a particular table in database? Hopefully this notification would tell you who did what?

How would I go about setting it up?

I would appreciate if you can point me out to the right direction.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am using version 14

Comment: Are you using **v14** (commonly referred to as SQL Server **2017**), or are you talking about SQL Server **2014** (internally v12) - please clarify

Comment: SQL Server 2017 - sorry!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? At one point it sounds like you want to track when a connection is made. Then it sounds like you want to know if somebody selects data from a table. And then it sounds like you want to audit ALL DML statements. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sure, look into the many auditing features... or create custom triggers that write to audit tables.

Comment: @SeanLange - I want to know who accessed the database... that is all

Comment: @scsimon - can you please direct me somewhere where I can pick this up?

Comment: OK what do you mean by who accessed the database. Meaning you want to track when any connection is made to the server? Otherwise I don't know that you can do that. And what do you mean by accessed? Remember connections are made to a server, not a database (although there is an initial database). You could use extended events to track queries but then you are crossing over from accessing the database to a MUCH more detailed look. Any idea what information you want to store?

Comment: @SeanLange - okay. since it is a shared server, perhaps there is no need to track all who accessed it. I need to see who accessed my particular database (or who queried it) ?

Comment: That means you are going to have to track every single query the runs against your database. What datapoints are you thinking you want to see? Meaning username, query, when it happened? Is this only for data retrieval or also add, edit, delete? You really need to dial this question in, it is still so vague and broad nobody can offer much at all in the way of help.

Comment: @SeanLange - I apologise, I did not realise it is that broad.. Yes I want to see who did what and when. More importantly, I want to see any edits or deletes, more than anything else. If it makes it easier, I would only want to see them two options.. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to audit every single value in every single table when anything is modified or deleted? And for the third time, what data points? I think you need to think about this a little bit and figure out what you really want. Do you want to track the queries? The data before and after? Whodunnit? When they did it? It sounds like what you really want, which is a LONG way from your original post, is full auditing of all the data. This can become incredibly deep and complicated very quickly.

Comment: @SeanLange - Ok - once again, I apologise. I am not well versed in SQL Server. Only 1 table I would like to target. In particular, only 2x columns in that table. Basically it is a payment table, I want to see if there has been any changes to who got paid and how much. Strictly speaking, once a payment is submitted, it should stay there untouched. However, for extra security, I want to have this tracking to detect fraudulent activity. Thanks

Comment: For me this sounds like you could just use the Sql Server Profiler with appropriate Filters

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn Profiler has been deprecated in favor of extended events for quite a while now. But this does sound like a reasonable approach. Although with the new information that it is only a single table perhaps a trigger for auditing is the simplest approach.

Comment: No offense mate but your question has been like drinking from a fire hose. It went from a huge amount of work to now only being concerned with 2 columns in one table. I would think this might be a good time to learn triggers. But still it is not at all clear what you really want to capture. Maybe you need to design the table to hold the information you want captured?